# How to parse output zod schema without redeclaring?

Tags: zod

When I have this schema

```js
export const Schema = z
  .object({
    cover_image_path: z.string().nullish(),
  })
  .transform((prev) => ({
    coverImagePath: prev.cover_image_path,
  }));
```

I can do

```js
Schema.parse(input);
```

What if I want to do something like

```js
Schema._output.parse(Schema.parse(input));
```

to avoid declaring another Schema

```js
export const Schema = z
  .object({
    coverImagePath: z.string().nullish(),
  });
```

Already tried to work with `_output` but it seems it is just the `Output` type

Answer (score 0):

Zod schemas are composable. I suppose you could try something like this.

```js
export const coverImageSchema = z.object({
  cover_image_path: z.string().nullish(),
});

export const transformingCoverImageSchema = coverImageSchema.transform(
  (prev) => ({
    coverImagePath: prev.cover_image_path,
  })
);
```

Comment: I think that would require the original object and return the original object, was wondering if there was a way to produce A => B (decoder) and B => A (encoder), just by declaring the first decoder.

Comment: Have you taken a look at ```Schema._def.schema```, it will give you access to all the sub components of your original schema. You would be able to access the schemas applied that happen before the transformation operation occurs. That would still not be a B => A though.